# OpenVPN Server Config Assistance (Bridging Connections)

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a virtual Ubuntu machine running an OpenVPN server. I'd like the connecting clients to access the LAN behind said server. The VM running OpenVPN has a bridged connection to the LAN.

```
OpenVPN: 10.8.0.1/24
LAN: 192.168.1.0/24
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.254
OpenVPN Server LAN IP: 192.168.1.224
```

I've tried forwarding traffic from the Tun0 interface using MASQUERADE but I'm not having any luck. I've also tried pushing a route to the DG in the server.conf file but the connecting client is still unable to ping any other machine on the LAN besides the host.

I thought that the solution might be to bridge the connection from the tun0 adaptor to the ens33 adaptor (LAN) - is this possible? what would the solution be here? Apologies if I've skipped over any detail, my networking knowledge isn't fantastic.

Server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap0
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server-bridge 192.168.1.224 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.128 192.168.1.254
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 127.0.1.1"
push "route 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Am I missing or misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `server-bridge`. Usually I just go with `server`.

I don't remember ever using the `sndbuf`, `rcfbuf`, `topology subnet` either. Although assuming your OpenVPN service starts and your client properly connect, we could argue: "it's not broken, ...".

You will need some iptables rules. Something like:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --src 10.8.0.1/24 --out-interface eth0 --jump MASQUERADE
```

This would allow all traffic, and make sure your OpenVPN clients traffic is NAT-ed to your OpenVPN Gateway's LAN IP, when accessing your LAN.

And what I suspect you're missing:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```